# IOS SWIFT removing an item from an Array does not work in my TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a notifications class with the following function (ed of post) that returns an array, I call the function (getListOfNotifications) below and get an array of data from my main ViewController.  In my main controller I define the array like such:

```
var arr = []
arr = getListOfNotifications(“\(userIdInt)”)
```

Then in my prepareForSegue I pass the array to a tableView

```
let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as       NotificationsTableViewController
secondVC.notificationsArray = arr
```

Then in the Tableview I have the following, which was populated from above,

```
var notificationsArray =  []
```

then in my tableview when I try to do the following delete, I can’t use the removeObjectAtIndex on the array, but I also can’t define the array as NSMutableArray.  What can I do to remove the item from the array?  I tried redefining it any which way possible and I can;t get anything to work.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
    notificationsArray.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
 }
```

This is the function in my Notifications class that I populate from a web service:

```
func getListOfNotifications(item:String)->Array<Notifications> {

    var notificationArray:[Notifications] = []

     println("==== Notifications ====")

    var url=NSURL(string:”http://www.mywebsite.com/NotificationListJSON.php?id="+item)

    var data=NSData(contentsOfURL:url!)

    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
        if let feed = json["notifications"] as? NSArray {
            for entry in feed {

                 var notifications = Notifications()
                 notifications.desc = entry["description"] as String
                 notifications.name = entry["name"] as String
                 notifications.iid = entry["iid"] as String
                 notifications.distance = entry["distance"] as String

                 notificationArray.append(notifications)
            }
        }
    }

    return notificationArray
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the array is going to be, why are you declaring it as an NSArray in the first place.  Why not:

```
var notificationsArray =  [Notifications]()
```

Then you'll have a swift array of Notifications, which is mutable and you should be able to remove.

Comment: agh, I hate when it is that obvious,  I am still learning Swift so the little things are making me struggle a little!  thanks so much... great way to end my evening, with working code!

Answer (score 0):

`removeObjectAtIndex` is a method of `NSMutableArray`, but you are working with a Swift array (declared as `var`, so also mutable).

Use the standard remove method described in the [Swift Standard Library References](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html).

```
notificationsArray.removeAtIndex[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: I think because of `var notificationsArray =  []` notificationsArray is actually being instantiated as an NSArray (non-mutable).

Comment: No, the keyword `var` indicates that it is mutable. Did you actually read my answer? It says this there *explicitly*.